# Load value in ref only when requested in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, computed-properties

In my Vue project, I have a `ref` variable that contains some data loaded from a DB. As a reference, it lives inside a [Pinia's setup store](https://pinia.vuejs.org/core-concepts/#Setup-Stores).

My goal is to load the value only when requested by user, and then always return it once it is loaded, to avoid unneded DB access.
The approach would be like:

```
// Create the "ref" in a smart way <- TODO
const myRef = ref(
  // something like:
  // return myRef ?? readMyRefFromDB();
);

...

// User access the value
console.log(myRef.value); // <- first usage: access DB and fill value property

...

// User re-access the value
console.log(myRef.value); // <- next usage: no need to access DB, return value
```

Currently, my approach is that, whenever one needs to access `myRef.value` I firstly call `readMyRefFromDB`, which does nothing if value already exists. However, this forces me to always use at least 2 lines to do it, and it's very error prone when used several times.

Another approach I can think of is to use `computed` getter, however I'd need to access property from inside its own getter, and that should not be possible. A possible solution might then be to use a dummy `ref` that gets populated inside the `computed` of `myRef`, but might not be ideal:

```
const dummyRef = ref();

const myRef = computed(() => dummyRef.value ?? readMyRefFromDB());

function readMyRefFromDB() {
  dummyRef.value = db.load('myRef')
  return dummyRef.value;
}

...

// User only accesses myRef
console.log(myRef.value);
```

Is there a better (Vue-friendly) approach?

Answer (score 0):

Although you could build something like this yourself, you might consider checking out [VueUse](https://vueuse.org/) for the `computedAsync` function. Specifically, you might want the `lazy` option [described here](https://vueuse.org/core/computedAsync/#lazy).

The library is high quality, and we are using it extensively in our projects. Many features available beyond this specific need.

Comment: Please add some code to show an example solution.